# Building with Tex not working from Python

Tags: python, latex

I've installed LaTex through

```
pip install latex
```

And also run the Mactex installer from here: https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

But when I try to build with Tex through Python, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write_case_insert_from_json.py", line 341, in <module>
    output_pdf_filename)
  File "trace_case_insert.py", line 245, in compile_tex_into_pdf
    pdf = latex.build_pdf(open(tex_filename))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/latex/build.py", line 234, in build_pdf
    raise RuntimeError('No available builder could be instantiated. '
RuntimeError: No available builder could be instantiated. Please make sure LaTeX is installed.
```

Why can't Python find tex? What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you confirmed that LaTex is installed on the machine?  Not the python package, but the actual LaTex engine.

Comment: `pip install latex` does not install latex, but this should install all you need: `brew install texmaker`, `brew install mactex`, `brew install latex-mk`. This is the package that was installed with `pip`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/latex/0.6.1